# How to access a list that is inside ViewModel from another ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to learn WPF MVVM pattern and I can't figure how to access variables that are inside ViewModels from other ViewModels.

I have 2 Views, LogInViewModel and MenuViewModel, in LogInViewModel I have my Employee list that I load form memory and I use this list to check if Employee with entered password exists after the uses clicks a Log In button, in my MenuViewModel I want to access this Employee list that is in the LogInViewModel.

How can I access this Employee list from MenuViewModel that is inside LogInViewModel?

EDIT : I ended up having all data in a static class called Database, because the list is now static I can access it form any ViewModel.

Comment: As a general hint, a view model structure would typically roughly resemble the structure of the views. For example if there is a main view with a set of child views, there would be a main view model with a set of child view models. The child view model instances would be held by properties of the main view model. No view except the top level would set its own view model.

Comment: Look into [dependency injection](http://www.ninject.org/).

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, that was a helpful hint )

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Well, this can be achieved in many different ways-

1. Passing the employee list as an argument in the constructor of the other VM.
2. Passing the whole VM as an argument in the constructor of the other VM. That way you will have access to all the properties present in the first VM.
3. Make the employee list static and then you can easily access it from any class.

   ```
    class VM1
    {
        public static List<string> EmpList = new List<string> { "Emp1", "Emp2" };
    }
    class VM2
    {
        public List<string> EmpList = VM1.EmpList;
    }
   ```
4. Or you can make a Model and have a static variable of its type declared in the Model itself. And access it from anywhere. e.g.

   ```
    class EmpModel
    {
        public static EmpModel Employees = new EmpModel();
        public List<string> EmpList { get; set; }
    }
    class VM1
    {
        void method1()
        {
            EmpModel.Employees.EmpList = new List<string> { "Emp1", "Emp2" };
        }
    }
    class VM2
    {
        void method2()
        {
            List<string> EmpList = EmpModel.Employees.EmpList;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Which one is more accepted in MVVM pattern?

Comment: I would recommend the 4th option.