# Xamarin MVVM Android - Method getting called multiple times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, behavior

**EDIT:**
*The problem seems to occour only when the list have at least one checked checkbox.*

I'm using Xamarin with MVVM and i have a CollectionView of Products and a checkbox.
I have a list of Products implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.
By using EventToCommandBehavior i call a Command when a checkbox is checked, binding the object as a CommandParameter.
This command calls a Method called CheckPrice. This method checks if the Found property of the object is true and proceeds if it meets the condition (the IsChecked of the checkbox is binded to the Checked property of the object). After this check, the object is updated and then the method RefreshList is called, this method makes the list receive a new list from the database.

The problem is, every time the list is updated (through the RefreshList method) and the Notify() method of the List set is called, the CheckPrice method is called multiple times until i click cancel on the DisplayPrompt.

This appears to happen every time i refresh the ItemsSource (the Products list on the viewmodel).

**View XAML**

The CollectionView on the View

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" x:Name="List">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  Margin="0,-21,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Found}">
                <CheckBox.Behaviors CachingStrategy="RetainElement">
                    <xct:EventToCommandBehavior                                                            
                        EventName="PropertyChanged"
                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.CheckPrice, Source={x:Reference List}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </CheckBox.Behaviors>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**ViewModel**

The list of Products that acts as the ItemsSource for the CollectionView

```
public List<Product> Products
{
    get { return produtos; }
    set { produtos = value; Notify(); }
}
```

The method that is being called by the CheckPrice command

```
private async void UpdatePrice(Product product)
{
    var str = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Product Found!", "Type the price", "Save", "Cancel", keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
    if (str != null)
    {
        product.Price = Decimal.Parse(str);
        App._productRepo.UpdateProduct(product);
        RefreshProd();
    }
}
```

The RefreshList method that is called everytime i add or remove something (also called on the constructor of the viewmodel)

```
public void RefreshList()
{
    this.Products = App._productRepo.GetProducts();
}
```

Among a lot of things, i tried to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and that solves the problem, but that way my RefreshList method won't work (i have to close the page then open it again to refresh).

Comment: I don't see why an `ObservableCollection` would solve the problem, but if it does you should use that.  Why do you need to reload the entire dataset when just one product changes?  It seems like that logic could be rewritten and simplied to avoid the problem.

Comment: @Jason seems like ObservableCollection won't notify when the list is updated (item removed / added), so the problem does not occur. Is there a better way to update the list with safety? As i said, the problem seems just occur when the Notify() method of the List set is called, so if i find a better way to update the list without setting a new one, i believe that would help.

Comment: @leaf "ObservableCollection won't notify when the list is updated (item removed / added)", you have that exactly in reverse. `ObservableCollection` raises events when something gets added or removed, while `List` doesn't do that. There must be something else going on here. With `ObservableCollection` there is no need to replace the entire collection everytime something changes.

Comment: again, why are you updating the entire list when one price changes?  Why not update just that item?  If `Product` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then the UI should automatically refresh when a price is changed

Comment: @ewerspej I´m reviewing the code right now, the ObservableCollection it's not updating.

Comment: @Jason i'm looking right now, neither `ObservableCollection`  or `Product` implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` automatically refresh the UI.

Comment: then you are doing something wrong.  Please post the code for `Product`

Comment: @Jason
The guy who previously coded this code was setting a new list from db and not updating the list, so, it was not notifying any changes. I'm testing with ObservableCollection and it's working but i'll have to change a considerable amount of code for everything to work. This is the first project i'm in (i'm a trainee) so i'm kinda confused still. Thank you both for your help. I'll try and finish evertything and will let you guys know how it goes.

Comment: Just one more thing (atm). what's the best pratice for acessing a method / property in a ViewModel from another ViewModel? I saw some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184069/how-to-access-a-list-that-is-inside-viewmodel-from-another-viewmodel), but want you guys opinion if that's ok. Thanks!

Comment: @ewerspej yeah, i was following my co-worker code, since he's a bit more experienced than me. I think i got know, Thanks!!

Comment: **1)** If you've got it working, please add "Your Answer" below, showing what worked. **2)** *"viewmodel to viewmodel"*: Try MessagingCenter Publish/Subscribe. Search for docs or previous Q&As. If necessary, create another question - its best not to ask new questions within comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code was updating the entire list when i deleted or added anything to it, so there was no notify. Now i'm using ObservableCollection without replacing the entire list.